# Add values in select query in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

How do i add values in the select query? example in my code below i have 5 gold, 2 silver and 1 bronze. 1 gold is equal to 3 points and 1 silver is 2 points. My question is how do i compute for this in the select query? is it possible?

Here is my php script

```
$sql = "SELECT team.shortcut,
            SUM(IF(rank = 1, 1, 0)) AS gold, 
            SUM(IF(rank = 2, 1, 0)) AS silver,
            SUM(IF(rank = 3, 1, 0)) AS bronze
        FROM team 
            INNER JOIN academicorg ON team.shortcut = academicorg.shortcut 
        GROUP BY shortcut 
        ORDER BY gold DESC, silver DESC, bronze DESC";                         

$con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name); 

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$response = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    array_push($response, array("shortcut"=>$row[0], "gold"=>$row[1], "silver"=>$row[2], "bronze"=>$row[3], "total"=>$row[4]));
}

echo json_encode (array("news_response"=>$response));
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here is what i get

```
    {"news_response":[{"shortcut":"aaa","gold":"6","silver":"3","bronze":"5","total":null},

{"shortcut":"bbb","gold":"6","silver":"3","bronze":"4","total":null}
```

Here is what i want. I got the total of 29 because gold is equal to 3 points and silver is 2 and bronze is 1.

```
 {"news_response":[{"shortcut":"aaa","gold":"6","silver":"3","bronze":"5","total"29},

{"shortcut":"bbb","gold":"6","silver":"3","bronze":"4","total":28}
```

Comment: I don't understand. What do You want to do?

Comment: I think you'd have to wrap the select within another select. It might be easier just to do the math within your while loop.

Comment: Show your inputs and show your desired results

Comment: [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: added the results sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be tempted to try this. Its not tested I dont have a database that fits requirements

```
SELECT team.shortcut,
    SUM(IF(rank = 1, 1, 0)) AS gold, 
    SUM(IF(rank = 2, 1, 0)) AS silver,
    SUM(IF(rank = 3, 1, 0)) AS bronze,
    SUM(IF(rank = 1, 3, IF(rank = 2, 2, IF(rank = 3, 1, 0)))) as total
FROM team 
    INNER JOIN academicorg ON team.shortcut = academicorg.shortcut 
GROUP BY shortcut 
ORDER BY gold DESC, silver DESC, bronze DESC
```

Comment: @Strawberry That might have worked except OP stored Gold with a Rank of 1  and Bronze with a rank of 3. So I dont think that would work

Comment: @RiggsFolly You''ve lost me :-(

Comment: @Strawberry Maybe if you expand on your comment a bit, maybe I misunderstood

Comment: In MySQL (specifically) `SUM(IF(rank = 1, 1, 0)) AS gold` can be replaced with `SUM(rank=1) gold`